# How does a process handler of a single-cored computer get control back from a process?

Tags: multiprocessing

On a single-cored computer there is only one real/physical point of control. How can the process handler get the point of control back when it wants, when the only point of control is in hands of the current process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hardware interrupt from the interrupt controller. This could be from an external device, such as a hard drive notifying the CPU that a DMA operation has completed or a UART indicating data is available to be read from its registers. Most often it is from a timer/clock cycle counter. Before the OS runs user-mode code, it configures this clock to interrupt after a certain number of clock cycles and configures an interrupt handler which invokes the OS's scheduler code.

All of the above is for a preempt-able OS, which encompasses nearly every modern OS. In the old days, the OS could not interrupt user-mode code. The user-mode code had to call back into the OS before another process could be scheduled. Obviously this meant that one program could freeze the entire system permanently.